# voice based translation from one language to another in windows phone os

Tags: windows-phone-8

My project is to do a translator based on the voice only .The user need to give the input in the form of voice in their native language. Then the system need to produce the translation in the user preferred language. The problem for is the i don't know how to set the voice recognition in different language . please help me. thanks in advance i am doing this in  windows phone 8  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs for Windows Phone, but you will need to use two to accomplish what you are trying to do.  First, you need to use the speech recognition to convert the speech to text.  Then, run this through the Microsoft Translator to translate to another language.  Note that for the speech recognition, you should query for the appropriate speech recognizer for the language that is spoken.

See the following links:

[Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Microsoft Translator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/developers.aspx)

Comment: Thank you . Does It continuously recognize?

Comment: The speech recognition API will only decode words or short phrases.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example here of how to build the Windows Phone 8 app for Translator:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/windowsphone8.aspx

You could use this with voice-captured instead of text-entered input.